# Error inflating a GridView on a tablet

Tags: android, gridview, classcastexception, inflate

I'm using a `GridView` in my Android app. Everything works perfectly on my phone, but when I tried to run the app on a tablet emulator, it crashed at the start.

The error is `E/AndroidRuntime(466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{****/***.Main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{***/***.views.calendar.CalendarView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView`
The line #42 has simply a `<GridView>` tag in it.

Then the stacktrace says `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class android.widget.GridView`, `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` and finishes with:

```
02-11 23:57:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(466): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from drawable resource ID #0x1020004
02-11 23:57:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1874)
02-11 23:57:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-11 23:57:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:711)
02-11 23:57:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.widget.GridView.<init>(GridView.java:76)
02-11 23:57:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(466):  at android.widget.GridView.<init>(GridView.java:72)
```

I don't use any LayoutParams, my xml layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_relativeLayout_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_relativeLayout_infoBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/calendar_infoBar_background" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/calendar_imageButton_previousMonth"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_prev" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/calendar_imageButton_nextMonth"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_next" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calendar_textView_currentMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="February 2012"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_gridView_currentCalendar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendar_relativeLayout_infoBar"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:id/empty">
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I don't understand is that how come a `GridView` is workable on a phone and not workable in a tablet...

Thanks in advance for any clues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:listSelector="@android:id/empty"
```

As far as I know the [listSelector attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3alistSelector) expects a reference to a drawable, not an id. `@android:id/empty` can be used to declare an optional 'empty' view for ListView and GridView, and I'm pretty sure it's not meant to used as above. See [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) for more details. Try referencing an actual drawable (or color), e.g. `@null` or `@android:color/transparent` to make the selector 'invisible' (or just set the height to '0').

Alternatively, you could be using resource qualifiers that prevent a tablet from finding the appropriate resource. Have a read through the ['How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource'](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) explanation for some more details. However, since you're not referencing a drawable resource directly in your GridView declaration, I doubt this is the issue.

Comment: It worked! I changed to a color and it worked! Thank you so much!!! I'm so happy right now.